# How to check network bandwidth capacity in my Ubuntu device?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, network-monitoring, nic

I need to check my ethernets cards network bandwidth capacity. The software instructions gives this command:

```
sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Speed
```

But when I try to run it in Ubuntu, I get this error:

> sudo: ethtool: command not found

Q1: How can I list the network cards names in Ubuntu 18?
Q2: What is the equivalent command to perform the task of the posted command?

EDIT:
I did install `ethtool`. But I do not get the speed. Just `Settings for wlp2s0: Link detected: yes`

Comment: You need to install ethtool first. `sudo apt install ethtool`.

Comment: I did. But I do not get the speed. Just `Settings for wlp2s0: Link detected: yes`

Comment: For wireless network cards use `iwlist bitrate`.

Comment: That's what I get: `lo no bit-rate information.
wlp2s0    unknown bit-rate information.
Current Bit Rate:6 Mb/s`